# How to grab items with specific value in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm setting up a table of people in DynamoDB, and I'd like to tag those people.

For demonstrations purposes lets say those tags are just strings... "tall", "short", "likes baseball" and so on...

How can I set up the data so I can quickly query all the people with a specific tag, like all the "tall" people?

Can I avoid scanning the table? Can I avoid creating multiple tables? Is this actually a much better use case for relational data structures? What if I come up with new tags on the fly? Relational doesn't work in that case.

**Update:**

`People     Tags         Mappings
======     ====         ========
John       firefighter  John  > firefighter
Sally      young        John  > young
Joe        owner        Sally > owner
Anne       staff        Anne  > owner
Chris      zebra-lover  Chris > zebra-lover
Ben        42           Ben   > zebra-lover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to avoid scanning when you want to query an attribute which is not the primary key, you can use [global secondary keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). For your case that probably doesn't work well, as you might want to be able to tag people with multiple tags at once.

Therefore I'd instead go for a separate table which just contains mappings of tags to people. In that table one item should be the mapping of one tag to one person. If a person has multiple tags, just add multiple items in there.

That way you'd query the tag-table for a given tag to get the primary key of all the people you're searching and would do another query against the people-table afterwards to get their details.

That works for new tags as well, as they'd mean just additional items in the tag-table.

Comment: I've almost got it. Let me update my question with what I understood...

Comment: So, if I wanted all the Zebra Lovers, I'd query my mappings table for zebra-lover, and it would spit back a list of people's id's (or names in our example)... Then, we'll do several get item requests for each of the names? What if we have hundreds of thousands of zebra lovers? Is that still okay performance wise?

Comment: In your updated question you have three tables, but you only need two. The "tags"-table you have is not necessary. Instead in the "Mappings"-table use the tag as primary key. Then you can query that table for tags and get the people belonging to these tags.

Comment: Ah, good point! But how do I get the relevant people in one query, after I have the result from the tag table? It returns a list of ids, after all. Doesn't that lock me into doing one get item request per person?

Comment: You could use a [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html)-request to fetch multiple items at once.

Comment: Mmm... okay. Makes sense. Thanks : )